# My Laravel 8 Auth works fine on XAMPP Local Server but when hosted on cPanel, it doesn't pass authentication rather on login, shows Page Expired

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I developed an application with Laravel also using the Laravel Auth for authentication, the authentication works well on the local server, with no issues at all. I decided to host it online. On the login page, when I input the username and password, it doesn't even query the DB to know if the credentials are correct or not, it justs returns an error page (419 Page Expired). It's been 3 days now and I'm getting frustrated. please I need help.

Comment: Have you uploaded your site via ftp or pulled it from a repo? If the former approach was used then maybe you have cache stored values , it happened to me once, make sure to have a fresh db when deploying via `php artisan migrate:fresh` and try to run `php artisan optimize:clear` followed by `php artisan optimize`

Comment: check if you are adding crsf token on the login form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

419 Page Expired means you have missed `csrf_token`

Check if it is written inside your form tag:

use `@csrf` if not

Comment: i'm using @csrf in all my forms, my application works properly on Xampp but not on cPanel server

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@csrf` or `{{ csrf_token() }}`.
Then ensure `VerifyCsrfToken` Middleware

> protected $except = [
> '*',
> ];

I hope it will be work.